# FTP Publish Error in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: ftp, visual-studio-2013, publish

I've been working on an old Visual Studio 2010 Project which is published via FTP,

as part of my process I have updated the project to Visual Studio 2013 and attempted to republish onto the server to my test environment, upon doing so I get the following error,

```
    Publishing folder /...
    Unable to add 'About.aspx' to the Web site.  An unknown WinINet error has occurred (code 12113).
```

it then continues to list every file in my Site with exactly the same error message

I've gone back to the VS 2010 Project and it still works perfectly with exactly the same FTP settings, looking round the net there are a number of people asking similar questions with regards to VS 2013 but I can't find one that is solved.

I watched the publishing folder on the server and when i published a new file was created in the folder, (something like `ProjectName`.publish.xml) so the connection is working right?? but why the error?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

in my case the issue was in firewall rules. You have to add **inbound** rule for Visual studio. In my case the files marked in VS with this error still appeared on the server, so, as I understood, this error means that VS cannot receive a message from the target server that file transfer completed correctly.

Answer (score 48):

When setting up the login parameters of the FTP in the profile setup in VS - under connection, make sure "Passive mode" is checked.
That solved my problems.[image]

Answer (score 2):

In my case VS 2015, i change publish setting of connection ==>checkded on "passive mode" and then it worked.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lYmk.png)

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you've managed to find a solution by now, but I'll leave this here just in case any one else comes across it.

I had two publishing profiles, one for Azure/TFS and one for GoDaddy(FTP). While trying to publish to GoDaddy the Microsoft login popped up that I'd normally see when publishing to Azure. I just closed it but this seems to have triggered the problems. Logging in seems to have resolved the issue.

Answer (score -1):

This turned out to be a firewall issue on my Dev pc. The files were being written but no response to say they were successfully deployed.